# Filename extensions missing in Notes document

Tags: lotus-notes

I have an issue with $FILE field with few Notes documents.
The issue is that they don't have filename extensions. And those $FILEs which don't have filename extensions do not have proper filenames too. 
For example, if there are two attachments present in an email(image1.jpg and image2.jpg), and if I open this email document in Notes client(in the backend), one of them will not have an extension for the filename and this one will not have the actual filename too. If image1.jpg is the one whose extension is missing, it's filename will be seen as some random characters. 
I have attached [a screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n67ye.png) of it. 
Please suggest what could be the issue.
Thanks.

Comment: Don't work with $File items. Work with Notes backend classes. They care about $File items automatically.

Comment: Are you creating those docs programmatically? Or are these just existing docs that your program has to handle?

Comment: The "Random" characters are actually Notes' reaction to the fact that the files had the same name when they were attached.  If you detach them (with the NotesEmbeddedObjects class) and rename it, you'll be fine.  How can you prevent it?  You can't, unless you can keep a sender from attaching the same file twice (hint: you can't.)

Comment: @Duston Thanks for the reply but unfortunately that is not the case. I just tested it the way you mentioned. Sent an email with two attachments twice(image.png and image.png). But when I checked for the $FILEs, both have correct filenames and extensions, only Notes has chnaged one of them to image.001.png

Comment: That was probably your mail client helping you out instead.  If you have a file upload control on a Notes form, what I described will happen.

Answer (score 0):

As commented by Duston: what you see is internal behavior to handle duplicate file names attached to Notes document. Original filename is stored (I believe) in Body field referencing that $FILE item.

Once user uploads the same filename twice, there is no way to recover the original filename.

Comment: After monitoring the documents for many days on our production environment, it is now clear that if there are more than one attachments by the same name, then the rest of them will face this issue. But I have been trying to reproduce the same in development environment, but as mentioned earlier, when I attach two or more files with the same name, then the others will be prefixed with 001,002 and so on by Notes itself. The reason for this difference is not yet clear.

Comment: Take a look at the client version.

Comment: The client version is the same for all environments.

Comment: Different filename format **might** be caused by MIME/Rich text format. That property is in location document, if you tried it via memo in mail.